# Selecting from an XML Variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I get a row for each X from the following:

```
<XML>
  <X>apple</X>
  <X>pear</X>
  <X>orange</X>
</XML>
```

I've tried

```
SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(25)') as value FROM @TitlesXML.nodes('/XML') as T(N)
```

but what I get is

```
applepearorange
```

anything else I try gets me nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
DECLARE @TitlesXML XML = N'<XML>
                            <X>apple</X>
                            <X>pear</X>
                            <X>orange</X>
                           </XML>'

SELECT N.value('.[1]', 'varchar(25)') as value 
FROM @TitlesXML.nodes('/XML/X') as T(N)
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════╗
║ value  ║
╠════════╣
║ apple  ║
║ pear   ║
║ orange ║
╚════════╝
```